# HTML Hyperlink to a specific scene in a swf file

Tags: html, actionscript-3, hyperlink, flash

I have an swf file with many scenes. I would like to be able to add multiple hyperlinks to a company Intranet site (set up on SharePoint) that link to specific scenes in the swf file. Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: Could you show what you have tried?

Comment: I don't have anything to show at this point. To be honest, I wasn't sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

It's do-able... it's going to depend on how much access you have to the actionscript, the javascript, etc. In short you'll need to be able to add the necessary listeners required to do what you want to do.

I found an example of communication between JavaScript and Flash here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-communicate-between-flash-and-javascript--active-3370

Comment: Thank you @diggersworld ! I will dig into this before the week is out. I appreciate the help. I will dig into the tutorial & comment if I get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, first you need to setup deep-linking in your SWF. Check out [swfaddress](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/). This will make it easier to create deep-links (using the browser address hash) into your SWF file. For example, a url such as `my/site.html#scene3` could `gotoAndPlay(1, "scene3")` in your SWF. Swfaddress has various examples to get you started.

Once you have your swf setup to support deep-linking, you can simply create HTML links with the desired url, like `<a href="my/site.html#scene3">`.